# Re-writing simple jQuery into pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, code-translation

I'm building a JavaScript plugin which will bolt onto other websites.

The whole thing is written with pure JS but there's one bit I haven't been able to get away from jQuery with:

```
var key = "some_key";
var selector = "#my_input, input[name=my_input], .someInputs";
jQuery(document).on('change', selector, function() {
    doSomething(key, this.value);
});
```

The reason I want to avoid jQuery is that I expect this JS to be included in a wide range of sites, many of which won't have jQuery. Some will have other frameworks already installed such as Mootools, some will have old versions of jQuery where `.on()` isn't supported, etc.

That, and I am ideally trying to keep it very lightweight, so adding in jQuery just for this tiny task seems excessive.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: @mc01: Thanks for the comment - I'm aware of how to add event listeners with pure JS - should have mentioned that the part I was struggling with was mostly to do with finding elements matching the selector across different browsers, but minitech's answer solves that a treat

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here’s some futuristic JavaScript that does exactly the same thing:

```
var key = "some_key";
var selector = "#my_input, input[name=my_input], .someInputs";

document.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    if (e.target.matches(selector)) {
        doSomething(key, e.target.value);
    }
});
```

However, [several browsers only support it with a prefix](http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchesselector), so it’ll be closer to this:

```
var matches = (function () {
    var names = ['matches', 'matchesSelector', 'mozMatchesSelector', 'webkitMatchesSelector', 'msMatchesSelector'];

    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        var name = names[i];

        if (name in HTMLElement.prototype) {
            return HTMLElement.prototype[name];
        }
    }

    return null;
})();

var key = "some_key";
var selector = "#my_input, input[name=my_input], .someInputs";

document.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    if (matches.call(e.target, selector)) {
        doSomething(key, e.target.value);
    }
});
```

Assuming the selector isn’t dynamic and you need delegation, you can still do the verbose, manual check:

```
var key = "some_key";

document.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    var target = e.target;

    if (target.id === 'my_input' ||
            target.nodeName === 'INPUT' && target.name === 'my_input' ||
            (' ' + target.className + ' ').indexOf(' someInputs ') !== -1) {
        doSomething(key, target.value);
    }
}, false);
```

As @T.J. Crowder points out, although this works for input elements, you’ll need to check an element’s parents in many cases. Here’s some even more futuristic JavaScript to accomplish the task:

```
function* ascend(element) {
    do {
        yield element;
    } while ((element = element.parentNode));
}

var key = "some_key";
var selector = "#my_input, input[name=my_input], .someInputs";

document.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    var match = Array.from(ascend(e.target)).find(x => x.matches(selector));

    if (match) {
        doSomething(key, match.value);
    }
});
```

If you smashed Firefox Nightly and Chrome together, this would work in that browser. We don’t have that, but feel free to shim `Array.prototype.find`!

Comment: +1 and works for the likely elements the OP has. Just a note: This doesn't handle one important bit of event delegation, which is triggering even the event originated on a *descendant* element of the element that matches the selector. E.g., `.on("click", "div", ...)` fires with `this = div` when you click the **`span`** here: <div><span>foo</span></div>`. To do that bit, you have to check `e.target`, then (if it doesn't match), its parent node, and *its* parent node, etc., until you reach the element you hooked the event on.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Good point! I’ve added some code that I wish worked *today* for that. =D

Comment: LOL! But beware, if you're not rooted in `document`, you'll go out of bounds. Alternately, of course, there's...a boring old `for` loop. *(Gasp!!)* ;-) `for (var node = e.target; !matches.call(node, selector); node = node.parentNode) { if (node === this) { return; } } doSomething(key, node.value);` (formatted: http://pastie.org/9427419). (You might need to check against `document.documentElement` rather than `document` if rooting in `document`. I never root in `document`, I use `document.body`.)

Comment: @minitech: Great help thanks. Had to also add `true` as the third `addEventListener()` parameter as some sites using this had their own change event listeners preventing the event from bubbling up to the `document` level where my listener is